# Iterate through xml and save text as csv

Tags: xml, loops, elementtree

I need to iterate through my xml and output the text within the city and snm <> and transfer these to a csv with column names city and name.

I have tried this using the iter() function with elementtree and I can see my results when I apply print .text but when I save these as a dataframe only the names output correctly, the cities output the same one several times.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("EP02736775NWB1.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

with open('patent.csv', 'w', newline='') as patent:
writer = csv.writer(patent)
writer.writerow(['City', 'Name'])

for city in root.iter('city'):
    cities = city.text
    print(cities)
for name in root.iter('snm'):
    names = name.text
    print(names)

    row = (cities, names)
    writer.writerow(row)

    df = pd.read_csv('patent.csv')
    df.head()
```

I would expect the dataframe to have a column containing a list of cities and column containing a list of names

Comment: you seem to have an issue with your code indentation. Could you please provide an example of the xml file and what you expect to be the output?